# My friends cannot join my Minecraft server but I can join theirs

Tags: technical-issues, minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one, minecraft-bedrock-edition-server

I play on *Minecraft: Windows 10 Edition*, and since I updated to the new 1.12 version my friends get a simple (can't connect to world) message. However, I can join anyone's game.

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling, hard resetting my Xbox and router and I have checked my NAT type which is Open. If anyone has a solution, please let me know.

Comment: Is everyone playing on 1.12? I know that some people haven't been receiving the latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your default spawnpoint is not obstructed. If you want, try and place it again. You will need to enable commands for this.

I had the same problem with my friends, and that was because I had being playing in the Nether.

Be sure to have your **spawnpoint** and the **world's spawnpoint** both in the overworld *(*`spawnpoint` *for the player and* `setworldspawn` *for the world, both set the spawn where you cast them)*. I also made sure to stay in the overwold while they entered for the first time, but that shouldn't be necessary.